# Implementation of Math.isFinite() method

Tags: java, floating-point, nan, infinity

To check if the value is `NaN`,
we can use `Double.isNaN()`.
in [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Double.java#Double),
implementation is like this.

```
public static boolean isNaN(double v){
    return (v != v);
}
```

`Double.isInfinite()` is like this.

```
public static boolean isInfinite(double v){
    return (v == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) || (v == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
}
```

However, `Double.isFinite()` is like this.

```
public static boolean isFinite(double v){
    return Math.abs(v) <= Double.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

So my first question is,
Why not simply returns `!( Double.isNaN(v) || Double.isInfinite(v) )` ?
Are there any performance reasons?

I think A is faster than B. Is this wrong?

A. one `!=` , two `==`s, two `||`s, and one `!`
B. `abs()` and `<=`

My second question is,
" is this completely identical ?"
that is,
" does this method return `true` ? "

```
public static boolean test(){
    long x = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    for(;;){ //iterate from Long.MIN_VALUE to Long.MAX_VALUE
        double d = Double.longBitsToDouble(x);
        boolean a = ! ( Double.isNaN(d) || Double.isInfinite(d) );
        boolean b = Double.isFinite(d);
        if(a != b) return false;
        if(x == Long.MAX_VALUE) break;
        x++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: With your method, you do an infinite loop going from minimum value of an signed long to the maximum value. I bet that takes longer than `Math.abs` and `<=`.

Comment: @AndrewL.   read my question again carefully.

Comment: First, my `test()` method will not do an infinite loop .  (but takes very very long time) .  Second,  obviously , my `test()` method is not for checking given `double` value,  just for restate my question cleary.

Comment: I'm saying it's an infinite loop, but of course you break out of it. I mean the loop itself is infinite

Comment: You can use a do/while loop `do { } while (x++ < Long.MAX_VALUE)` instead of `for (;;)`

Comment: `"Why not simply returns" can you explain how that is simpler?

Comment: You state A is doing 6 operations and B is doing 2 but you conclude A is simpler and faster?

Comment: BTW ON x86, FABS is a single instruction http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_80.html

Comment: @PeterLawrey   It seems faster  for me.  I want to know why B is faster than A.  `Math.abs(double a)` is like this, `return (a <= 0.0D) ? 0.0D - a : a;`   At hardware level, is there no difference between `==` and `<=` ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey   If java use FABS,  I can understand why.

Comment: Math.abs becomes a single machine code instruction. All it does is clear the signed bit which is trivial.

Comment: @PeterLawrey   Really? because it is included in language specification ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey   so, believing GrepCode is sometimes dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.abs(double) is faster than it appears

```
return (a <= 0.0D) ? 0.0D - a : a;
```

as the methods is recognised as an intrinsic in HotSpot and many other JVMs. An intrinsic is replaced by code which does the same thing, but more efficiently.

See [vmSymbols.hpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/classfile/vmSymbols.hpp#l774) for a list of symbols which are replaced by hand coded machine code.

> so, believing GrepCode is sometimes dangerous.

GrepCode tells you what the source looks like. It is hard to second guess what optimisations will be performed on Java code when it is converted to native code. The JIT has clever optimisations, dead code elimination which can make optimisation which look faster/smarter run slower.

If in doubt, stick to the simplest code, and it is likely the JIT has a special optimisation for it. Try something tricky and you might find, the JIT doesn't have an optimisation for it and it will be slower.

Comment: Thank you.   Is such optimization guaranteed to be completely identical with " Java representation " ?   i.e.  " is my second question true?"  i.e.  "does my `test()` method return `true` " ?

Comment: @ShuS All possible numbers should be Infinite, NaN or Finite.  Note: there is about 2^52 possible NaN values, but Java assumes there is only one. I don't think it will be a problem in your test.

Comment: I see. Then I will use `isFinite()` . Thank you very much .

Comment: @ShuS given the method is 20 years old, it is likely that any bugs in this method have been fixed by now. Note: a fix to Math.round(x) was added in Java 7, so these things do happen.

Comment: I understand.  I'll use carefully.